# Dividing through user input value in VBA formula calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I get stuck with using an user input decimal (currency conversion e.g. 1.12) in the calculation of my formula. I am not sure how to refer to the `myvalue` in the formula and also if I need to dim it as double or vartype?

The entered value e.g. 1.12 should be used in all 3 Range rows for the calculation, but now I am getting a name error as the formula doesn't recognize `myvalue` after I have run the macro. What am I doing wrong with the definitions?

```
' convert_in_EUR_column_GHL Macro

Dim gRow As Long, hRow As Long
Dim myvalue As Double

gRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
hRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

myvalue = InputBox("Enter 2 decimal currency conversion rate")


Range("M2").Resize(gRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(RC[-6]/myvalue,"""")=0,"""",RC[-6]/myvalue),"""")"
Range("N2").Resize(hRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(IFERROR(RC[-6]/myvalue,"""")=0,"""",RC[-6]/myvalue)"
Range("O2").Resize(hRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(IFERROR(RC[-3]/myvalue,"""")=0,"""",RC[-3]/myvalue)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not implementing it incorrectly.

`Range("M2").Resize(gRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(RC[-6]/myvalue,"""")=0,"""",RC[-6]/myvalue),"""")"`

Should be

`Range("M2").Resize(gRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(RC[-6]/" &  myvalue & 
 ","""")=0,"""",RC[-6]/" &  myvalue & 
 "),"""")"`

as the formula will not be able to evaluate `myvalue` part which is a variable stored in memory. Similarly, you should be able to fix other formulas.

Comment: Just one question, how long will the user value be saved in stored memory?

Comment: @Robert, it depends on the scope of variable. Read this [link](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/variables/lifetime-scope.htm) to understand better.